# Are date calculations faster in PHP or MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

A while back a database administrator mentioned to me that some server-side programmers don't utilize `SQL` as often as they should. For instance, when it comes making time-based calculations, he claims that `SQL` is better suited.

I didn't give that much consideration since it didn't really affect what I was doing. However, now I am making considerable time-based calculations. Typically, I have used `PHP` for this in the past. For the sake of performance, I am curious as to whether `SQL` would be more efficient.

For example, these are some of the tasks I have been doing:

```
        $todaysDate = date("d-m-Y");
        $todayStamp = strtotime($todaysDate); //Convert date to unix timestamp for comparison
        $verifyStamp = strtotime($verifyDate); //Convert submitted date to unix timestamp for comparison

        //The date comparison
        if((strtotime($lbp) <= $verifyStamp) && ($verifyStamp <= $todayStamp)){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            $invalid = "$verifyDate is outside the valid date range: $lbp - $todaysDate.";
            return $invalid;            
        }
```

The variables aren't that important - it's just to illustrate that I am making comparisons, adding time to current dates, etc.

Would it be beneficial if I were to translate some or all of these tasks to `SQL`? Note that my connection to my database is via `PDO` and that I usually have to create a new connection. Also, my date calculations typically will be inserted into a database. So when I say that I'm making comparisons or adding time to a current date, I mean that I'm making these calculation before adding whatever results from them to a query:

i.e. `$result = something...INSERT INTO table VALUE = $result`

The calculations could just as easily be `INSERT INTO table VALUE = DATE_ADD(...`

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Why not set up a test and time it?

Comment: Personally, I like the idea of doing as much calculation as possible on the end user's machine (assuming they have JavaScript enabled)

Comment: Calculate with PHP as much as possible but do not fetch more rows from the database than needed. Web servers are more easy to multiple than database servers so database load should be kept to minimum.

Comment: @webnoob You have a valid point, but I am curious as to other's experiences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overhead of talking to the database would negate any and all advantages it may or may not have. It's simple: if you're in PHP anyway, do the calculations in PHP. If the data you want to do calculations on is in the database, do it in the database. Don't transition between systems just because unless you can really proof that it saves you a ton of time to do so (most likely it doesn't). What you're showing is child's play in either system, it hardly gets any faster as it is.

Comment: I figured as much. That's essentially why I stated that I have to make a new connection each time.

Answer (score 1):

Well when you consider SQL with any of the programming language, then using SQL is more preferable for calculations than any other language.

If you consider Php and SQL then I would like to tell you what I have realized from my analysis..

The `PHP` architecture is a client-server architecture, that is **Client sends a HTTP-Request to the Server and the server responds back to the client with HTTP-Response**

One the backside of the server, the server generates a simple HTML Format page which is static that page is generated using the dynamic codes of PHP on the server.

Now the total time is:

**HTTP-Request** + **SQL-Query** + **Fetching data from SQL Query** + **Data Manipulation of SQL Data** + **Php-to-HTMLGeneration** + **HTTP-Response**

But if in case you use the calculations to be done within the SQL Query itself then the time for **Data Manipulation of SQL** in php would be saved. As the Php would have to deal with the datas explicitly.

So the total time would be:

**HTTP-Request** + **SQL-Query** + **Fetching data from SQL Query** + **Php-to-HTMLGeneration** + **HTTP-Response**

This may look almost equal if you are dealing with less amount of data. But for an instance if you are dealing with ***1000*** of rows in one query then a ***loop*** in php which would run 1000 time would be more time consuming than running a single query which would calculate the complete 1000 row in just one command.

Comment: The work has to be done *somewhere*. If you do it in the database, then the database query will be a little slower. Likely not noticeably so, but neither will it be very noticeable if you do the calculation in PHP.

Comment: @deceze: I tried it.. I made a 200x200 array and the elements were saved in database that is I had 40,000 elements as in total and in each query 81 rows where pulled out. The calculation at the SQL end was noticeably faster than getting the query and doing the data manipulation on the PHP side.

Comment: Sure, I didn't say you should never do it in the database. But you do need a good reason to. If the data is coming from the database anyway, do as much as possible with it in the database. But it seems the OP was considering doing calculations in the database on data not coming from the database.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is how many date calculations you are performing and where in the query your conversion is taking place.  If you are searching a DB of 10 million records and you are converting a DateTime field into a Unix Timestamp inside of a WHERE clause for every single record and only ending up with 100 records in the query result it would be less efficient to use SQL to perform that conversion on 10 million records than it would be to use PHP to convert the DateTime object into a Timestamp on only the resulting 100 records.

Granted, only the result of 100 records would be converted anyway if you put the conversion in the select statement so it would be pretty much the same.

Comment: so your suggesting reading 10 million rows from the database to php to do the calculation?

Comment: Absolutely not!  I'd either search by some other key if possible or search by the actual DateTime string instead.  The point I was trying to make is that where you place the date conversion in the query has a large effect on resource cost of the query.  If you absolutely must (for some strange reason) convert every row's value from a DateTime to an integer it would definitely be easier to do it in the DB.